# responsive iframe src param based on parent container size

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, autoresize, window-resize

I'm working on a responsive page whereby there's a embeded video content.

How can I update the parameter width/height in the iframe src as well as the iframe attribute width/height based on the width of the parent container as well as change when the window/orientation changes?

My mark-up:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="video">
    <iframe src="http://www.foo.com/embeddedPlayer?id=4062930&width=672&height=377&autoPlay=false" width="672" height="377" border="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Heres my JS:

```
var articleBodyWidth = $('.content').width(),
    videoUrl = $('.video'),    
    videoSrc = videoUrl.find('iframe').attr('src'),
    iframeWidth = videoUrl.find('iframe').attr('width'),
    iframeHeight = videoUrl.find('iframe').attr('height');

// function to get param in url
function getParam(name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(videoSrc);
  if(results == null) {
    return "";
  } else {
    return results[1];
  }
}

var newWidth = articleBodyWidth,
    newHeight = Math.round( (iframeHeight / iframeWidth) * articleBodyWidth );

// update iframe width and height
videoUrl.find('iframe').attr({
   width: newWidth,
   height: newHeight
});
```

Comment: Updated my question with code.

Comment: @calebo find my updated answer, whether it solves the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do

```
$('.video iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.foo.com/embeddedPlayer?id=4062930&width=' + newWidth+ ' &height='  + newHeight + ' &autoPlay=false').css({
   width: newWidth,
   height: newHeight
})
```

Another solution is to use regex to replace height and width in the src

```
function updateVideo() {
    var src = $('.video iframe').attr('src');
    src = src.replace(/&width=\d+&/, '&width=' + newWidth + '&');
    src = src.replace(/&height=\d+&/, '&height=' + newHeight + '&');
    $('.video iframe').attr('src', src).attr({
       width: newWidth,
       height: newHeight
    });
}

$(window).on('resize', updateVideo)
```

Comment: would it be possible to update the values when my window resizes/device orientation change?

Comment: You need to use `$(window).on('resize', function(){})` event handling

Answer (score 0):

What you'll have to do is control the size with CSS.

`<iframe src="http://www.foo.com/embeddedPlayer?id=4062930&width=672&height=377&autoPlay=false" border="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="video"></iframe>`

```
<style type="text/css">
#video { width:100%; height:auto: }
</style>
```

I stripped the width and height from `<iframe>` so CSS could take over.

Comment: unfortunately I can't do that as the iframe url I receive has to have params parsed in.

Answer (score 0):

@kcdwayne is right. You should put the CSS in control in a responsive page.
For an embedded video the only variable is "height", but if you use @media-queries you can set height for different screen sizes, depending on layout changes.

Here's how I would try doing it:
http://tinyurl.com/a2cxfe6

More info about embedded flash object here:
http://www.aleosoft.com/flashtutorial_autofit.html

Comment: I have no control over the height/width of the flash object, the page generated with width & height base on the url param.